# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (works when a separate sql, but does not work inside a oracle function)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i, ora-00942

When I have a sql statement like `select * from table1`, it works great, but as soon as I put it into a function, I get:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Maybe the function belongs to a different schema than the table?

Comment: Strongly related: [oracle “table or view does not exist” from inside stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4198052/1377865)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could look at. Based on your question, it looks like the function owner is different from the table owner.

1) Grants via a role : In order to create stored procedures and functions on another user's objects, you need direct access to the objects (instead of access through a role).

2)

> By default, stored procedures and SQL methods execute with the
>   privileges of their owner, not their current user.

If you created a table in Schema A and the function in Schema B, you should take a look at Oracle's Invoker/Definer Rights concepts to understand what might be causing the issue.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809

Answer (score 55):

There's a strong chance that the privileges to select from table1 have been granted to a role, and the role has been granted to you.  Privileges granted to a role are not available to PL/SQL written by a user, even if the user has been granted the role.

You see this a lot for users that have been granted the dba role on objects owned by sys.  A user with dba role will be able to, say, `SELECT * from V$SESSION`, but will not be able to write a function that includes `SELECT * FROM V$SESSION`.

The fix is to grant explicit permissions on the object in question to the user directly, for example, in the case above, the SYS user has to `GRANT SELECT ON V_$SESSION TO MyUser;`

Comment: would you be able to update this answer with a complete PROCEDURE example using that technique?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not working at a job that uses Oracle anymore, so I don't have a machine to test the validity of any syntax I'd write.  If some else wants to take a stab at it, though, be my guest.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the function is in the same DB schema as the table.

Comment: If the function is inside a package, the package also needs to belong to same schema as the table?

Comment: Yes, it does. Or else, it will not be able to find the table. Unless you include the schema name in the select: `select columns from schema.table1`

Answer (score 2):

Either u dont have permission to that schema/table OR table does exist.
Mostly this issue occurred if you are using other schema tables in your stored procedures.
Eg. If you are running Stored Procedure from user/schema ABC and in the same PL/SQL there are tables which is from user/schema XYZ. In this case ABC should have GRANT i.e. privileges of XYZ tables

Grant All On  To ABC;

```
Select * From Dba_Tab_Privs Where Owner = 'XYZ'and Table_Name = <Table_Name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to add the database name with your table name like if your DB name is `DBMS`  and table is `info`  then  it will be `DBMS.info` for any query.

If your query is

```
select * from STUDENTREC where ROLL_NO=1;
```

it might show an error but

```
select * from DBMS.STUDENTREC where ROLL_NO=1;
```

it doesn't because now actually your table is found.

Comment: I had the same problem, if you dont know the schema, you can try option #3 here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00942.php,

For this example it would be: `SELECT owner
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW')
AND object_name = 'STUDENTREC';`