# To kill session using procedure for Sql ID

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have made the procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE KILLSESSION AS 
BEGIN
for rec in (SELECT sid,serial# 
  FROM v$session 
 WHERE status = 'ACTIVE' 
   AND username ='NCMAIN' 
   AND sql_id ='bzq9gwv2qazpq' ) loop

execute immediate 'Alter System Kill Session '''|| rec.Sid || ',' || rec.Serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE';

 end loop;
END KILLSESSION
```

I am getting error that table or view does not exists and use of Loop variable rec is invalid. I have created procedure in DBA schema.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (works when a separate sql, but does nto work inside a oracle function)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669575/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-works-when-a-separate-sql-but-does-nto)

Answer (score 0):

You need SELECT privileges on V$SESSION. You need these direct (not granted via a role).

To check whether you have the necessary privileges, you can use the 'set role none' command in SQL/Plus:

```
SQL> select count(*) from v$session;
23
SQL> set role none;
Role set
SQL select count(*) from v$session;
ORA-00942 table or view does not exist
```

To fix it, run

```
   GRANT SELECT ON v$session TO <my_dba_user>
```

as SYS