# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, plsql

I create a package with the body of the package. The package itself is compiled, but the body does not. The tables are created, the fields are present, the types are correct. But it gives an error
32/5 PL / SQL: SQL Statement ignored
49/17 PL / SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Help solve the problem.

````
 create or replace package dma.fill_account_turnover_f is
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  c_MartName                       constant varchar2(30 char) := 'dma.DM_ACCOUNT_TURNOVER_F';

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /**  –асчет оборотов по счетам за дату
   *   i_OnDate - дата расчета
   */
  procedure fill
  ( i_OnDate                       in date
  );
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

end fill_account_turnover_f;
/
create or replace package body dma.fill_account_turnover_f is
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  procedure Log
  ( i_message                      in varchar2
  ) 
  is
  begin
    dma.logger.writeLog('[' || c_MartName || '] ' || i_message);
  end;
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  procedure fill
  ( i_OnDate                       in date
  )
  is
  begin

    Log( '[BEGIN] fill(i_OnDate => date ''' 
         || to_char(i_OnDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
         || ''');'
       );
    
    Log( 'delete on_date = ' 
         || to_char(i_OnDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
       );
    delete
      from dma.dm_account_turnover_f f
     where f.on_date = i_OnDate;
   
    Log('insert');
    insert
      into dma.dm_account_turnover_f
           ( on_date
           , account_rk
           , credit_amount
           , credit_amount_rub
           , debet_amount
           , debet_amount_rub
           )
    with wt_turn as
    ( select p.credit_account_rk                  as account_rk
           , p.credit_amount                      as credit_amount
           , p.credit_amount 
             * nvl(er.reduced_cource, 1)          as credit_amount_rub
           , cast(null as number)                 as debet_amount
           , cast(null as number)                 as debet_amount_rub
        from ds.ft_posting_f p
        join ds.md_account_d a
          on a.account_rk = p.credit_account_rk
        left
        join ds.md_exchange_rate_d er
          on er.currency_rk = a.currency_rk
         and i_OnDate between er.data_actual_date   and er.data_actual_end_date
       where p.oper_date = i_OnDate
         and i_OnDate           between a.data_actual_date    and a.data_actual_end_date
         and a.data_actual_date between trunc(i_OnDate, 'mm') and last_day(i_OnDate)
       union all
      select p.debet_account_rk                   as account_rk
           , cast(null as number)                 as credit_amount
           , cast(null as number)                 as credit_amount_rub
           , p.debet_amount                       as debet_amount
           , p.debet_amount 
             * nvl(er.reduced_cource, 1)          as debet_amount_rub
        from ds.ft_posting_f p
        join ds.md_account_d a
          on a.account_rk = p.debet_account_rk
        left 
        join ds.md_exchange_rate_d er
          on er.currency_rk = a.currency_rk
         and i_OnDate between er.data_actual_date and er.data_actual_end_date
       where p.oper_date = i_OnDate
         and i_OnDate           between a.data_actual_date and a.data_actual_end_date
         and a.data_actual_date between trunc(i_OnDate, 'mm') and last_day(i_OnDate)
    )
    select i_OnDate                               as on_date
         , t.account_rk
         , sum(t.credit_amount)                   as credit_amount
         , sum(t.credit_amount_rub)               as credit_amount_rub
         , sum(t.debet_amount)                    as debet_amount
         , sum(t.debet_amount_rub)                as debet_amount_rub
      from wt_turn t
     group by t.account_rk;

     Log('[END] inserted ' || to_char(sql%rowcount) || ' rows.');

    commit;
    
  end;
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

end fill_account_turnover_f;
/ ```
````

Comment: The line number in the error message shows you which table it gives the error for. Could this be you're running into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669575/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-works-when-a-separate-sql-but-does-not) issue

Comment: Line 49 refers to `ds.md_account_d`. The package appears to belong to DMA, so maybe DS needs to grant READ privileges  on MD_ACCOUNT_D to DMA. You have my sympathies for working with a multi-schema system, as the design may look great in Powerpoint but they just create endless problems in my experience.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You're right. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 49 refers to `ds.md_account_d`. The package belongs to DMA, so probably DS needs to

```
grant READ on MD_ACCOUNT_D to DMA;
```

along with any other privileges that are needed.