# Oracle procedure to move tablespace

Tags: oracle, procedure

Friends...
I'm testing this Oracle procedure to move all tables, indexes of a tablespace to new tablespace... I'm trying to debug and fix this simple procedure but it gives me cursor error... could somebody please point my error?

I can generate something manually but there are 200 tablespaces there which I plan to move at regular interval so wanting to automate this task.

Objective: Accept old tablespace and new tablespace at procedure run and use it to move all objects in that tablespace to new tablespace.

1. I plan to do something like below:

   1. Accept old_tbs, new_tbs at procedure run
   2. Move Table A from old_tbs to new_tbs
   3. Rebuild indexes of Table A to new_tbs
   4. Move Table B from old_tbs to new_tbs
   5. Rebuild indexes of Table B to new_tbs

loop...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure moveTbl (OldTbs in varchar2, NewTbs in varchar2)
IS

 TblSQL         VARCHAR2(250);

CURSOR curTable (vOwner varchar2, vTblName varchar2, vTbsName varchar2)
IS
   SELECT owner, table_name, tablespace_name
      FROM dba_tables
      WHERE tablespace_name = OldTbs
      ORDER BY 2;

 rec1 curTable%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  FOR rec1 IN curTable LOOP

   dbms_output.putline('rec1.owner || rec1.table_name');
     TblSQL := 'alter table '||rec1.owner||'.'||rec1.table_name||' move tablespace '||NewTbs;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TblSQL;

END LOOP;  --curTable for loop

END moveTbl;
/
```

Comment: This might be a better fit for [dba.se]

Comment: What error exactly do you get?

Comment: @Yarsir, error posted   LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/8      PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'CURTABLE' is incomplete or
         malformed

8/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/12     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
13/7     PL/SQL: Item ignored
16/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
16/15    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'CURTABLE'

Comment: @MikeW, never knew about dba section.. created question under there...

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74214/oracle-procedure-to-move-tablespace

Comment: As others have said, remove the cursor parameters. For the ORA-00942, are you able to query `dba_tables` directly? If so [your privileges might have been granted via a role](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4198052/266304).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the cursor as having three parameters, but you don't supply any parameters when you open it in the FOR loop. I suggest that this cursor doesn't need any parameters, and they should be eliminated.

It may also be the case that the schema/user under which this procedure is being created doesn't have access to the DBA_TABLES view.

### Edit

`AUTHID CURRENT USER` should be added immediately after the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` but before the `IS`, as shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE moveTbl (OldTbs in varchar2, NewTbs in varchar2)
    AUTHID CURRENT USER
IS
  CURSOR curTable IS
    SELECT owner, table_name, tablespace_name
      FROM dba_tables
      WHERE tablespace_name = OldTbs
      ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
BEGIN
  FOR rec1 IN curTable LOOP
    dbms_output.putline(rec1.owner || '.' || rec1.table_name);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || rec1.owner || '.' || rec1.table_name ||
                      ' move tablespace ' || NewTbs;
  END LOOP;  --curTable for loop
END moveTbl;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: User has got access to dba_tables I have verified that. will look into cursor parameter... thanks

Comment: As @AlexPoole noted above, the access of the user in question may have been granted via a role. To test this, execute `SET ROLE NONE` and then try to query DBA_TABLES - if the query fails it indicates access is granted via a role. A possible workaround is to add `AUTHID CURRENT USER` to the procedure declaration. Share and enjoy.

Comment: yes Alex and you are right... after SET ROLE NONE user was not able to query dba_tables (this is something new learning) ... how to add AUTHID CURRENT USER to procedure declaration...

Comment: @homer: I've edited the answer to include a definition of the procedure with `AUTHID CURRENT USER` added.

Comment: thanks and excellent solution... I can compile procedure correctly and can also do dbms_output.put_line to print "alter table table_name move tablespace new_tablespace" but when this gets executed it fails with ora-01031: insufficient privilege ... I tried manually running "alter table move... " command but it works without any error... so wondering is it something to with user permission or execute move table via procedure is different?

Comment: I'd have to think that it has something to do with user permissions, but that's an area I'm not as familiar with as I'd like. You should probably take this up with your local DBA.