# PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Inside Function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, max

I can view the result when I write the query outside the block but writing it inside function shows an error.

```
SELECT max(logid) FROM hawk.log_patch_execution_result;
```

Output:

```
461
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION latest_log_id RETURN NUMBER IS
v_log_id NUMBER; 
v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT max(logid) INTO v_log_id FROM hawk.log_patch_execution_result;
  RETURN v_log_id;
END latest_log_id;
/
```

Output:

```
Create function, executed in 16 ms
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Total execution time 16 ms
```

Comment: remove this from trigger please `hawkeyemaster5.` then try. or add it like this CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hawkeyemaster5.latest_log_id

Comment: `hawkeyemaster5.` is the schema of table `log_patch_execution_result`. In Which schema did you create function `latest_log_id`? `?

Comment: Are your privileges on that table granted directly to you, or via a role? It sounds like [that might be the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198165/266304).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table you're selecting from belongs to user `hawk`.

User, which uses the function, should be granted the `SELECT` privilege (on that table). I presume that you did that (as `SELECT` itself works OK, but not as part of a function) - via some role. However, that won't work - you should grant the privilege **directly** to user, not via role.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an issue in the schema/user you are working at.
Try to compile it in such way adding the schema name in the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hawk.latest_log_id RETURN NUMBER IS
v_log_id NUMBER; 
v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT max(logid) INTO v_log_id FROM hawk.log_patch_execution_result;
  RETURN v_log_id;
END latest_log_id;
/
```